Rotate element x degrees on scroll
I'm looking to rotate some elements on scroll. I want them to rotate starting from 0 degrees and then add or substract 25 degrees (or any other number) to the current degree value on each scroll up/down event.
Here's what I have. It works on first scroll, but then the value is not updated on scroll up or down.
What am I missing?


const elem = document.querySelectorAll(".rotator");
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  elem.forEach((el) => {
    let lastScrollTop = 0;
    let value = 0;
    let st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
      // Scroll down
      value += 25;
    } else if (st < lastScrollTop) {
      // Scroll up
      value -= 25;
    }

    el.style.transform = `rotate(${value}deg)`;
  })
})
.rotator {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;

}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 1000px;
}
<h1>Keep rotating on scrolling up or down</h1>
<div class="rotator">Rotate</div>
<div class="rotator">Rotate</div>




Scroll event isnt fired, use wheel event

Thanks, but it still only registers the first scroll event...

hmm move the variables lastScrollTop, value outside

Doesn't seem to fix it.

You keep resetting the values's to 0 in every iteration. Move the declaration outside the loops.

You're also never setting lastScrollTop, so I;ve added an
lastScrollTop = st;


let value = 0;
let lastScrollTop = 0;
const elem = document.querySelectorAll(".rotator");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  elem.forEach((el) => { 
    let st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
      // Scroll down
      value += 25;
    } else if (st < lastScrollTop) {
      // Scroll up
      value -= 25;
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
    el.style.transform = `rotate(${value}deg)`;
  })
})
.rotator {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;

}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 1000px;
}
<h1>Keep rotating on scrolling up or down</h1>
<div class="rotator">Rotate</div>
<div class="rotator">Rotate</div>




Small example using wheel event where you can check the event.deltaY to see the scroll direction and append that to the value.


let value = 0;
const elem = document.querySelectorAll(".rotator");

window.addEventListener("wheel", function (ev) {
  elem.forEach((el) =>
    el.style.transform = `rotate(${value += (ev.deltaY < 1) ? 25 : -25}deg)`)
})
.rotator {height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: lightgreen; }
body {display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between; height: 1000px; }
<h1>Keep rotating on scrolling up or down</h1>
<div class="rotator">Rotate</div>
<div class="rotator">Rotate</div>




Yes, that was it! Thank you very much for your time.
